# Using Android WifiP2P across multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I'm using the Android Wifi P2P technology in my android application to send simple data transmissions between multiple devices. I'm reading the Developer Guide for Wifi p2p, but the implementation seems like it is only built for one activity to use the Wifi direct service.

Following the guide, I created this BroadcastReceiver class to listen for Wifi Direct events:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;

public class WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private WifiActivity activity;

    public WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel, WifiActivity activity){
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity
        }else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers
        }else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections
        }else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
        }
    }
}
```

However, the constructor seems to only work with one activity.  Do I have to make a receiver for each and every activity that uses Wifi Direct? How do I pass the connection to different activities without having to set up the connection each time (i.e. find peers, connect to peer, etc)?

Comment: I don't see how you're using the activity. So, you're probably good  even if you remove it.... And sometimes you can replace the activity with a Context...

Comment: For example, in one activity, I'm listing peers.  In another, I'm transmitting data.  These activities have different methods, so how would I choose what activity class to cast the object to so that I can call the appropriate method?

Comment: First thing to say is that DO NOT PASS Activity as argument as much as you can because it might cause memory leaks. The solution could be you can send an broadcast receivers (use [localbroadcastmanager](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)) simply pass the intent that you received in you class to the other receivers inside your activities... I can post code if you want .... but all you need is in the tutorial that I mentioned here...

Comment: So I should statically create a master broadcast receiver on app load and use its onReceive to send a local broadcast to pass the data to the appropriate activity?

Comment: So you should create a broadcast receiver in each activity. but make sure you're using localbroadcastmanager and remember to register it in onResume and un-register it in onPause just to make sure only one activity receives the intent. and yes you have a general broadcast receiver that always receives the original intent and passes it to the activities...

Answer (score 4):

Although the answer is too late but since no one answered it, I thought of providing the solution.

You need to register the broadcast receiver with multiple activities, and change your constructor with the following code

```
public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,Context activity) {
        super();
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
    }
```

And wherever you need to change the code according to the activity, just check this

```
if(activity instanceof yourActivityName){
// your code based on the current activity
}
```

And register your broadcastreciever in your activity with this

```
receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

Hope this helps